# Binomial Random Variable Task

Tags: probability, expected-value, machine-learning

I have a question regarding probability and statistics...

A certain Friday evening 1% of the car drivers are intoxicated.
a) At a road check 50 drivers are tested. Compute the probability
that at least one intoxicated driver is caught.
b) At a road check drivers are tested. Let X be the number of tested
drivers when the first intoxicated driver is caught. Compute the
expected number E(X) and the standard deviation SD(X).

I wanted to try and use the following method:

X binomial random variable: X ~ Binomial (n, p)
where n is the number of trials (50) and p = P(success)

So for task a) we have p = 1/100, n = 50, P(X>=1)=1-P(X=0)=1-binomial(50,0) * (1/100)^0 * (1-1/100)^50

How can I calculate this? It seems a bit confusing to me so I'd really appreciate the help

Comment: For part a) calculate the probability that *none* are intoxicated.  Then your answer is 1.0 minus that probability.

Comment: ${50 \choose 0}(1/100)^0(1-1/100)^{50} \approx 0.605$ - also close to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For A), we have

$1.0 - (0.99)^{50}$, because that is the same thing as one minus the probability that no drivers are caught.

For B), we are dealing with a geometric distribution.

$E(X) = \frac{1-p}{p}$

Where p=0.01.

The variance is $E(X) = \frac{1-p}{p^2}$, so the square root of that is the SD.

Comment: Thank you! How can I calculate the probability that no drivers are caught? Sorry if I am asking for too much, I am new on this course and I feel very lost right now. Because when I do what you said, I get the correct number but I want to know how I got there...

Comment: The probability that no drivers are caught is simply 0.99 to the 50th power. This is because each driver has a 0.01 chance of being drunk, so they have a 0.99 chance of not being so. To not catch any, we need that 0.99 chance to happen 50 times consecutively.